# Angular Pass product ID to another function to get the ID image of that product

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a function that carries information from a product database.

How can I pass the ID of this product to the getImage function so that when it runs it finds the image with the ID of that same product?

**HTML**

```
  <div class="container-fluid first" style="cursor: pointer;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalPoll" >
      <div class="row tab-pane Galeria">
        <div *ngFor="let product of products" class="col-xl-2 col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
          <div class="image-item" (click)="fillModal($event, product)">
              <a class="d-block image-block h-100" >
              <homeImage> 
                <img *ngIf [src]="Images" class="Images img-fluid" alt="">
              </homeImage> 
              </a>           
            <div class="ImageText"> {{product.name}}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: what is your error here?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding simply call function by passing id

```
ImageInfo(product.id)
```

You can do one thing return path from this function and call it for src.

Something like this

```
<img [src]="ImageInfo(product.id)"/>
```

Comment: this but got an infinite loop for a service error and say you can't access the image because another process is already in use

Comment: my problem is calling the function in src ... if it doesn't work ... is there any way to get the product id without using product.id in src?

Answer (score 0):

```
  <img *ngIf [src]="ImageInfo(id)" class="Images img-fluid" alt="">
```

Write your image tag as show above and make sure the `ImageInfo` function returns the specific image as shown below.

```
  ImageInfo(id) {
      var self = this;
      self.Global.refreshToken().subscribe(function (result) {
        self.homeService.getImage(id).then(function (resultado) {
          if (resultado) {
            return resultado;
          }
        }).catch();
      });
    }
```

Comment: I'm starting to think the problem is with my service ... if you use [src] = product.id and run an infinite for service

Comment: my problem is calling the function in src ... if it doesn't work ... is there any way to get the product id without using product.id in src?